# Does this series converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, numerical-value

Let us consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\{\sqrt n\}-\frac 1 2} n$, where $\{\cdot\}$ denotes the fractional part
of a real number. On the one hand,

```
SumConvergence[(FractionalPart[Sqrt[n]] - 1/2)/n, n]
```

> `False`

On the other hand,

```
NSum[(FractionalPart[Sqrt[n]] - 1/2)/n, {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

> `-0.725204`

We have two contradictory results.

Let us investigate it.
The output of

```
N[Table[Sum[(FractionalPart[Sqrt[n]] - 1/2)/n, {n, 1, 10^k}], {k, 1, 5}], 15]
```

> `{-0.679200513405746, -0.755781168886997, -0.803827960877609, -0.810978369858450, -0.816045768107535}`

suggests the convergence, but the sum of the series does not equal `-0.725204`.
Let us look at the plots

```
DiscretePlot[(FractionalPart[Sqrt[n]] - 1/2), {n, 1, 121}]
```

[image]
and

```
DiscretePlot[(FractionalPart[Sqrt[n]] - 1/2), {n, 121, 144}]
```

[image]

The plots show that approximately from `k^2` to `(k^2+(k+1)^2)/2` (`k` is a positive integer) the terms are negative
and from  `(k^2+(k+1)^2)/2` to `(k+1)^2` the terms are nonnegative. Let us estimate the sums over these intervals
by

```
AsymptoticSum[1/n, {n, (k^2 + (k + 1)^2)/2, (k + 1)^2}, k -> Infinity]
```

> `1/k`

and

```
AsymptoticSum[1/n, {n, k^2, (k^2 + (k + 1)^2)/2}, k -> Infinity]
```

> `1/k`

This also suggests the convergence. However, the above is a plausible reasoning, not a proof.

The questions are: how to accurately prove or disprove the convergence with Mathematica? how to numerically calculate the sum of the series under consideration?

Comment: A harder question is about the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {\{\sqrt n\}-\frac 1 2} ne^{2\pi i t \log n} ,$$ where $t\in\mathbb R$ .

Comment: BTW, `SumConvergence[FractionalPart[Sqrt[n]]/n, n]` results in `True` instead of `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer to my question done with Mathematica. If `n>=k^2 && n<(k+1)^2`, where `k` is a positive integer, then `Floor[Sqrt[n]]==k` and `FractionalPart[Sqrt[n]]==Sqrt[n]-k`. Now we consider

```
Sum[(Sqrt[n] -k-1/2)/n, {n,k^2,(k + 1)^2 - 1},Assumptions -> k\[Element] PositiveIntegers]
```

> `1/2 (2 HurwitzZeta[1/2, k^2] - 2 HurwitzZeta[1/2, (1 + k)^2] +  PolyGamma[0, k^2] + 2 k PolyGamma[0, k^2] -  PolyGamma[0, 1 + 2 k + k^2] - 2 k PolyGamma[0, 1 + 2 k + k^2])`

```
Series[%, {k, Infinity, 2}]
```

> `-(2/(3 k^2))+O[1/k]^3`

This implies the series under consideration converges. In order to obtain the numerical value of the sum, we find

```
NSum[1/2 (2 HurwitzZeta[1/2, k^2] - 2 HurwitzZeta[1/2, (1 + k)^2] + 
PolyGamma[0, k^2] + 2 k PolyGamma[0, k^2] - 
PolyGamma[0, 1 + 2 k + k^2] - 
2 k PolyGamma[0, 1 + 2 k + k^2]), {k, 1, Infinity}]
```

> `-0.817595`

Comment: I'd like to elaborate the proof. Because of `Series[Sum[(Sqrt[n] - k - 1/2)/n, {n, k^2, (k + 1/2)^2}],   k -> Infinity]` which results in `-(1/(4 k))+O[1/k]^2` and 
`Series[Sum[(Sqrt[n] - k - 1/2)/n, {n, (k + 1/2)^2, (k + 1)^2 - 1}],   k -> Infinity]` which results in 
`1/(4 k)+O[1/k]^2`, the partial sum $S_n$ for $n\in [k^2,(k+1)^2]$ satisfies the estimates
$$S_n \ge S_{k^2}- 1/(4k)+O(1/k^2),\,S_n \le S_{k^2}+1/(4k)+O(1/k^2).$$
The squeeze theorem ends the proof.